# Virtuemart installation first page not working?

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart, installation, component-configuration

I'm trying to install Virtumart on my apache server.

I used this reference as my installation guide:
https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-install-joomla-on-an-ubuntu-18-04-vps-or-dedicated-server/

This is where got the package: http://virtuemart.net/downloads (full install)

The install page came but it's not working because the next button and some components are missing.

I need some expert help to fix this.  I tried different browsers, but still got the same result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour]. I have honestly tried to improve the English in your post, but if I have misinterpreted your message and my edit changes your question, please edit the question further.  Can you tell us what version of Joomla you installed before attempting to install virtumart? I am confused about the Next button -- it is visible -- does it not work? Are there any server-side or client-side errors generated by this page?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. No. I tried to install virtuemart package from the url in my question. The console has given this error: `JQurry not found.` Here is where I got the full install: http://virtuemart.net/download.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will solve the problem but it seems like you downloaded an outdated version of VirtueMart. Please, try downloading this one directly from Joomla Extensions: https://extensions.joomla.org/https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/virtuemart/

Last update was June 18, 2020. Version: 3.8.4